# how to show only 'Browse' button of asp fileupload?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I am using a FileUpload in my asp.net application. I want to show only 'Browse' button, I don't want to use any flash file.

How is that possible?

I am tried a [example](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle) but in this, btn style is getting change, textbox is showing, other [example](http://aspalliance.com/1441_Building_a_Gmail_Style_File_Uploading_System_using_ASPNET_20.3) this is also not solving my problem.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="ImageFileId" runat="server" class="file" />
<asp:Button ID="browse" runat="server" Text="Change Image" />

.file 
{
 visibility: hidden;
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 display: block;
}

$(function() {
$('#browse').click(function() { $('.file').click(); });
});
```

please give some example?

Comment: So you don't want to see the text box associated with a file input field? Is that correct?

Comment: You can play with the css of the input.You can see the path in the debbugger

Comment: Yes, I don't want to see textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example, note - you need to use `visibility: hidden` otherwise the browser won't perform the action for security reasons.

http://jsfiddle.net/tfeuk/1/

Comment: Just set the height/width to 0

Comment: On that same note, you need to set `display: block;` in order to take advantage of the height/width

Comment: its not working with asp button control, Browse btn is getting clicked but open dialog is not getting open.

Comment: Can you paste some of your code? It is hard to debug blind :)

Answer (score 0):

This is awesomw tutorial file upload using CSS
[GoHere](http://raffidotnetlearner.blogspot.in/2014/02/change-browsechoose-text-in-aspnet.html)